# Convert Physical Machine to Xenserver

Tags: xen

I am planning to convert all my physicals machines into Xen virtual machines.
But i can't find any documenation on that?

is it just to make a image file and convert it to a vdi ?
I may have to mention that is a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Headless server i need to virtualize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the XenServer version you want to use.
Unfortunately, XenConvert is retired since XS 6.2
There are two ways to do it:

Using old XenServer

1. Install XenServer 6.1 from CD
2. Convert the existing Linux with XenConvert
3. Export the VM image
4. Upgrade to XenServer 6.x (whatever you are planning to implement)
5. import/migrate the image

Using Clonezilla like described [here](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/548358-p2v-in-xenserver-6-2)

HTH